# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext, java.lang.Class

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to run my old selenium practiced scripts which were working fine before few months and are throwing errors now, especially at the constructor

> PageFactory.initElements(driver, Locators.class);

Stacktrace

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext, java.lang.Class)'
> at release.Preamble_cases.setup(Preamble_cases.java:69)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
> at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
> at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
> at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:637)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:627)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:589)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
> at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
> at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Selenium version used in pom.xml file is 4.11.0.

Only thing i did is to update the Eclipse version.
Earlier i was using 2023-03 and everything was working fine. Now it is 2023-09.

When i try to run a file without using Pagefactory, it works fine.